# How to get performance increases using Processing for Android?

Tags: java, android, performance, processing

I have converted a few of my Processing sketches into Android apps, but they seem to run really slowly in the emulator and on [my device](http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/XW-EN/Consumer-Products-and-Services/Mobile-Phones/Motorola-MILESTONE-XW-EN).

Are there any tips on how to increase the speed and performance of my sketch running as an Android app? Are there things or parts of the Processing API I should avoid?

Comment: http://wiki.processing.org/w/Android

Comment: I can find nothing about increasing performance from that link.

Comment: This might help - http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/10/gpu-rendering-in-adobe-air-for-android.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html
I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Facepalm to all answers...Their answers are for programmers that need every single % of the CPU optimized. But I have the same issue as you, not really having much going on in the sketch, but it's still slow. And I doubt BlackDragon even knows what Processing is

My answer:
Try using a different renderer,
P2D for example.

You can use it by putting it next to the sketch size definition:

```
size(Width,Heigth,P2D);
```

Or if you don't want to use that function, you can override the sketchRenderer by placing this method.

```
String sketchRenderer(){
   return P2D;
}
```